# How to delete not continuous data points in batches in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: database, time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

Is there any way to perform logical deletion in Apache IoTDB? When deleting multiple points, only one point can be executed in at a time. I know that deleting multiple points in a certain time range can be done using one command, but my requirement is that the time range is not continuous, such as I want to delete data points when `time=0` and `time=28` (in actual case the data points will be more). IoTDB can query jumping (not continuous) data points, so I want to know how can I delete jumping data points in batches in Apache IoTDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now the syntax you mentioned is not directly supported.
However, there are alternative solution in Apache IoTDB for your case. For example, you can consider retaining the original data and storing the processed (some are deleted) data in another time series. Or you can use writing method (such as `insert`) to write the corresponding repaired values for the corresponding data points, which is the same as you deleted the points. If you only want to do data cleaning, you can just use query statement to filter out the glitch data, so you do not need to delete the original data.